# Call method within servlet

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea

I have this servlet:

```
package com...servlet;

import com...Connector;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class AutomateServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AutomateServlet.class);

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connector con = new Connector();
    boolean test = con.start();
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("Servlet at: " + request.getServletPath());
    out.println("<br/>");
    out.println(request.getServerPort());

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```

}

And within Connector, I have a method:

```
public boolean start() {
  //gets data
  //communicates with an api to post content
    return true;
}
```

What I want to do: have AutomateServlet execute the line `con.start();` which is the meat of my program.
My issue is when I execute the servlet, ie call go to the servlet's url:

> localhost:2990/servlet/test

This is the output:

`Servlet at: /servlet/test 
2990`

The output is only half what I expect because `con.start()` does not get executed.

I know what my expected outcome should be- a page created using an api.
The thing is, when I run my project (IntelliJ) with my configurations, everything works fine. However, the servlet is glossing over the java code.
 I put in the `boolean` as a check to see the servlet's response.

Can you help me figure out why the `con.start()` does not yield the desired outcome? Again, the desired outcome is to create a page on another site. The business logic within `Connector.start()` is fully functional which is apparent when I call `start()` within the main method, but is not being processed when I call `conn.start()` in the `AutomateServlet` class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's completely unclear, what do you want to get? "The output is only half what I expect." - what do you expect? "conn.start() does not yield the desired outcome" - what do you want to see? Now you see exactly what you print - path and port.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question. 
What I want is the servlet to go to `con.start()` and execute the business logic before proceeding to the next set of instructions- `out.println("Servlet at: " + request.getServletPath());`... When I check to see if the method has been execute by verifying the location of the new page (from con.start()), it does not exist. Also, when I check the login count of the api I use, it does not increment. Meaning, the api is not even being accessed.

Comment: Does your `con.start()` method logic (which you hid) execute in the same thread, or does it launch some actions asynchronously, in another `Thread`/`Executor`?

Comment: I think it should be in the same thread- I'm not stating it launch asynchronously. I have no invocation of `Thread`/`Executor`. Do you think that would be wise to multithread, @RomanPuchkovskiy?

Comment: Does I understand you right: when you call `con.start()` from IDEA, it works, but when you call it from servlet, there is no result? Does your IDEA settings include some parameters/credentials/etc? "when I check the login count of the api I use, it does not increment" - may be, servlet code just doesn't have correct settings for connection?

Comment: Thats correct- when i call `con.start()` within my main method, everything works as it should. However, when I call `con.start()` within the servlet, the business logic does not execute. All of these classes are a part of the same project within IDEA with public variables (since business logic needs the variables in different classes anyway). But shouldn't the AutomateServlet class just launch the `con.start();` method. `con.start()` contains all the pertinent business logic...?

Comment: Are you sure your `con.start()` is not execute? May be, it's called, but fails for some reason when called from servlet? Did you debug your code or add some trace messages to connector logic?

Comment: Yes, I have some print statements within `con.start()`- they don't get displayed in my log file, nor the console, nor the response that is getting served via the servlet. The only response I see is from the lines:  ```out.println("Servlet at: " + request.getServletPath());
    out.println("<br/>");
    out.println(request.getServerPort());```